# Pass the lower limit to $-\infty$ for an integral of positive function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Hello I have an very elementary calculus problem.

Let $\phi(\eta)$ be a real value function satisfying
\begin{equation}
\phi(-\infty)=1,\quad \phi(+\infty)=0,
\end{equation}
Let $g$ be a positive function satisfying
\begin{equation}
g(0)=g(1)=0\quad\text{and}\quad g(u)>0\,\,\forall\,\,u\in (0,1).
\end{equation}
Now I want to know, where could the limit of the following integral lies in?
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\eta\to -\infty}\int_{\eta}^x g(\phi(s))\,ds
\end{equation}

I was given an answer that the limit exist, and yes I can see this because I think
$\frac{d}{d\eta}\int_{\eta}^x g(\phi(s))\,ds=-g(\eta)$ is telling me the above integral is a decreasing function on the half line $(-\infty, x)$ and so a the integral is a monotone and such function has a limit.

However I am not sure where exactly could the limit lies in? And I was told the answer, **the limit can either be non-negative real value or $+\infty$**. I am lost...
what does  $+\infty$ correspond to? and non-negative real value correspond to?

PS. Now if I let $x\to\infty$, can I claim the limit of this integral is strictly greater than 0? If not, what do I need to assume for the function $\phi$? $0<\varphi<1$?

Comment: Are we to assume $g(x)=0,\forall x \notin (0,1)$?

Comment: no, there is nothing more than what is stated there for $g$.

Comment: Nevermind...I just realized that the argument to the integrand never goes beyond $(0,1)$ anyway...:=P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example, let $g(x):= \frac{1}{x^2}-1$, in which case the integral *could* diverge to $+\infty$ (depending on how fast $\phi(x)$ moves away from zero and the value of $x$ in the limits.

In general,since $g(x)>0$ on $(0,1)$, and $\phi(x)\in (0,1),\;\forall x$ the integral must take only positive values. Thus, it must be either positive finite, or unbounded from above.

Comment: I am looking for a way that does not require me to guess what function could $g$ take, except the assumption given. Also, could you please edit your answer from "In general..." not quite clear what you mean...

Comment: @math101 my example was just that...I wanted to show how you can get $+\infty$. My second paragraph shows why in general, the integral will be $>0$

Comment: OK. "In general,..." is this a well known fact, to be honest , I've never heard of it til now from first year, what reference could help?

Comment: @math101 no references. How would the integral of a strictly positive integrand yield anything other than a value $>0$?

Comment: back to the idea of integration: calculating the area under the curve. Well if the curve never lies below 0, then the area should alway be positive...thanks

Comment: @math101 yep...and I gave an example that is $+\infty$, so that explains your answer.

Comment: could you please check my revised question if you are keen?

Comment: @math101 I don't see what you changed. Maybe add a PS? Or, better yet, just post a new question.

Comment: no worries. I added "PS."

Comment: @math101, I agree that you need to add some more restrictions on $\phi$. For example, the integral is not strictly positive if $\phi$ is zero everywhere except at $-\infty$

Comment: @math101 a sufficient condition is that it is continuous.

Comment: "except at $-\infty$..." what do you mean? Sufficient condition "what" is continuous, $\phi$?

Comment: @math101 $\phi(-\infty)=1$ and $0$ otherwise will make your integral equal 0. I was saying that requiring continuity of $\phi$ will force it to take positive values over some interval of $\mathbb{R}$, then the integral will become strictly positive.